# rcpp updating data in base environment

Tags: r, rcpp

I am working on a simple matching algorithm in Rcpp which is taking a number of individuals (I), a number of schools (J), a number of submitted choices (nc), a priority ranking of individuals (pos), the number of vacancy (emp), and the true choices..

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector gs2(int I, int J, int nc, NumericVector pos, NumericVector emp, NumericMatrix choices) {
    NumericVector admits(J);
    NumericVector out(I);
    std::fill(out.begin(),out.end(),J+1);
     for (int i=0;i<I;i++){
    NumericVector apply = choices(pos(i),_)-1;
     for (int j=0;j<nc;j++){
     if (emp(apply(j))>0)
     { 
      out(pos(i)) = apply(j)+1;
      admits(apply(j)) = admits(apply(j)) + 1;
      emp(apply(j))  = emp(apply(j)) - 1;
      break;
     }
     }
     }
   return out;
}
```

The code works fine.. Except that it looks like it is messing with my data.. after running the code my size variable has been changed...Am I missing something? Thanks

```
set.seed(123) 
rank      = (1:20)-1
stuchoice = matrix(sample(1:3,6*20,replace=T),byrow=T,ncol=6,nrow=20) 

size = c(7,11,4)

gs2(20,3,6,rank,size,stuchoice)
size
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `size` variable is changing because you are changing it in your C++ code.  In particular this line:

```
emp(apply(j))  = emp(apply(j)) - 1;
```

`Rcpp` passes variables by reference so anything you do to them inside will be reflected in your top R variables.  If you want to avoid this, then you want to `clone` your variable.  Changing your code to the following corrects the problem.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// Note the change in the name of 'emp' to 'emp_'!!!

//[[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector gs2(int I, int J, int nc, NumericVector pos, NumericVector emp_, NumericMatrix choices) {
    NumericVector admits(J);
    NumericVector out(I);

    // clone your emp
    NumericVector emp = clone(emp_);

    std::fill(out.begin(),out.end(),J+1);
     for (int i=0;i<I;i++){
    NumericVector apply = choices(pos(i),_)-1;
     for (int j=0;j<nc;j++){
     if (emp(apply(j))>0)
     { 
      out(pos(i)) = apply(j)+1;
      admits(apply(j)) = admits(apply(j)) + 1;
      emp(apply(j))  = emp(apply(j)) - 1;
      break;
     }
     }
     }
   return out;
}
```

Test

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("test.cpp")

set.seed(123) 
rank      = (1:20)-1
stuchoice = matrix(sample(1:3,6*20,replace=T),byrow=T,ncol=6,nrow=20) 

size = c(7,11,4)

gs2(20,3,6,rank,size,stuchoice)
size
[1]  7 11  4
```

Comment: Thanks! But when I create another variable like var1 = size.. It changes var1 too. How is that possible?

Comment: Because by setting `var = size` they are technically pointing at the same thing.  If you change `size` separately, for example `size = "foo"` then you are essentially redeclaring `size` whereas `var` is still pointing towards the original object in memory.

Comment: Yep :-)  If you are satisfied, please accept the answer.